# Cannot access object.id in postgreSQL with django app deployed to Heroku (internal server error 500)

Tags: python, django, postgresql, heroku

I deployed a Django blog app to Heroku and having problem accessing the objects through the objects' id.
When Debug=True in settings.py, everything works fine.
And even when Debug=False, there is no other problem such as static files issue, things are working fine. I searched many articles but most of them are about static files issues, not same as my situation.

First, My models.py:

```
class Post(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(verbose_name='TITLE', max_length=120)
    slug = models.SlugField(verbose_name='SLUG', unique=True, allow_unicode=True, max_length=120)
    content = RichTextUploadingField(verbose_name='POST CONTENT')
    create_date = models.DateTimeField(verbose_name='Created date', auto_now_add=True)
    author = models.ForeignKey(User, null=True, on_delete=models.CASCADE)

class Bookmark(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    slug = models.SlugField(verbose_name='SLUG', unique=True, allow_unicode=True, max_length=100)
    address = models.URLField(verbose_name='url', unique=True)
    description = models.CharField(max_length=256)
    category = models.ForeignKey(BookmarkCategory, on_delete=models.CASCADE, null=True, blank=True)
```

And in the urls.py:

```
path('post/<int:id>/', views.PostDetailView.as_view(), name='post_detail'),
path('bookmark/<int:id>/update/', views.BookmarkUpdateView.as_view(), name='bookmark_update'),
```

The problem occurs when I try to access my Post or Bookmark object in the templates using id, like:

```
{% url 'myblog:post_detail' post.id %}
```

or

```
{% url 'myblog:bookmark_update' bookmark.id %}
```

What I'm expecting is the DetailView or UpdateView of the objects, but instead I have internal server error (my 500.html shows up.)
I tried int:pk instead of int:id too, but just same error.

Again, things are totally fine when Debug=True, and also everything else works fine even when Debug=False.
There are several archiveViews based on the Post model and searching function, etc..they are all working.

So I tried changing the urls.py like:

```
path('post/<slug>/', views.PostDetailView.as_view(), name='post_detail'),
path('bookmark/<slug>/update/', views.BookmarkUpdateView.as_view(), name='bookmark_update'),
```

And then it just works! I can see the views I requested using slugs from the templates. Problem occurs only when I try to access the objects using the objects' ID.

So I suppose there is some problem with postgreSQL, possibly some problem with the way it stores objects' ID (maybe because ID is not explicitly defined in the models.py?), because when I worked with SQLite3 locally, there was no problem accessing through objects' ID.

For now I can just avoid the problem using slug instead of int:id but I want to use int:id because slug-based URLs are a bit too redundant.
Please anybody can help identifying what the problem is and what the solution may be?

Comment: There must be information in the logs. What does `heroku logs` show?

Comment: Can you see heroku's logs ?